# How to create an auto generated number

Tags: skyve

I am migrating existing data in to a Skyve application. The existing application has an auto generated number to identify the "request".

I found this : https://skyvers.github.io/skyve-dev-guide/utility-classes/#document-number-pattern

But how do I set an initial value?

Comment: Just an update to this one. 
As I need to run a Skyve job as part of the initial migration, I am calling this line in the job:  

`CORE.getNumberGenerator().next(PurchaseOrder.MODULE_NAME, PurchaseOrder.DOCUMENT_NAME, PurchaseOrder.purchaseOrderPropertyName)`  


it creates the ADM_DocumentNumber database entry.
I then just add some sql in an existing post-load-sql to update the "documentNumber" of that row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put an initial value into the corresponding record in admin.DocumentNumber document (ADM_DocumentName table).
You can either do this with an SQL insert as part of a deployment script or a manual deployment step through the admin module user interface (Admin->DocumentNumbers menu item)

If there is no DocumentNumber entry for the module/document/attribute combination, Skyve will create an entry starting at 1.

You can use something like

```
insert into ADM_DocumentNumber (bizId, bizVersion, bizLock, bizCustomer, bizDataGroupId, bizUserId, bizKey, moduleName, documentName, sequenceName, documentNumber) 
    VALUES (lower(newId()), 0, '20220714000000000admin', '<customer-name>', NULL, '<bizIdOf_ADM_SecurityUser>', '<module-name>.<document-name>.<attributeName>', '<module-name>', '<document-name>', '<attribute-name>', (select max(<legacy-column>) from <legacy-table>));
```